# Method to parse (want to assert the Meta-data under html file) HTML document in Typescript (Protrator )?

Tags: typescript, protractor

I want to assert meta-data of downloaded html file in protractor, Typescript

Comment: Is this meta-data contained in the page source? Could you post an example of what it looks like in the HTML

Comment: @DublinDev Ctrl+S on any web page then save it and after that I want to verify data under saved .html file, i.e. html parser in python I want to use in Typescript and Protractor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guyz for all your effort, no need to answer the query I have made it on my own, Please refer the created method of mine if you need-

Used npm library `npm install htmlparser2` took reference from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmlparser2)

```
var fs = require('fs-extra');
        var htmlparser = require("htmlparser2");
        var parser = new htmlparser.Parser({
            onopentag: function (name: string, attribs: string{ type: string; }) {
                if (name === tagName && attribs.type === attrType) {
                    console.log("=====================");
                }
            },
            ontext: function (text: any) {
                console.log("-->", text);
            },
            onclosetag: function (tag: string) {
                if (tag === tagName) {
                    console.log("======================");
                }
            }
        }, { decodeEntities: true });
        var rawHtml: string = fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(parser);
        parser.write(rawHtml);
        parser.end();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to capture any all meta tags using the following locator

```
element.all(by.tagName('meta'))
```

However if you want to save the HTML as a file and then parse that as you mentioned this is really not what Protractor is designed for. Protractor is designed for interacting with the browser as a user would. You could parse the HTML file using the `fs` npm package but this does seem overly complicated.